# Pass Requests to the right Application

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, tomcat7

I've got a problem with using nginx in front of Tomcat 7.
I want to proxy requests for a domain sub.domain.tld/*.jsp to http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapplication/*.jsp, but I can't manage to get it right.

I need to use sub.domain.tld/myapp/*.jsp in order to get the file showing, how is it possible to implement this redirection?

My current config is the one from the nginx wiki:
http://wiki.nginx.org/JavaServers

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u call response.sendRedirect("subdomain/log.jsp");